# Как запустить war в диспетчер служб iis?

Tags: iis, jar, war

Дали практику. Надо запустить WAR (или jar) через диспетчер служб iis. Как это делать? Есть какие нибудь начальные уроки для новичков?

Comment: war нужно запускать в контейнере сервлетов. Попробуйте Tomcat или Jetty. IIS тут никаким боком.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя напрямую запустить Java-приложение на IIS. Нужно использовать Java EE контейнер (Glassfish, Tomcat и т.д.)
Можно, конечно, использовать IIS как прокси, но смысла в этом не много.

Comment: А WAR тоже нельзя?

Comment: @Максим, нет. Это jar/war - это Java-приложения. IIS - это про Microsoft .NET, другая вселенная.

Comment: Прошу прощения за толстолобость, но что бы все стало мне понятно.  А .dll и .exe можно?